# Return dynamically generated zip file as json response when download button is clicked

Tags: python, django, html, django-templates, django-views

I am dynamically generating zip file with result after user searches for data. I want to return the zip file as a json response and allow user to download it when download button is clicked.

Below is the code i have used which returns HttpResponse. I want to convert this to a json response. I tried a few approaches and it didn't work. I am not sure how the url should be specified in the template and also the url pattern for the same.

Below is the code I have used in the view:

```
filename = "{}_{}.txt".format(query_word, doc_id)
zip_dir = "result_for_query_{}.zip".format(query_word)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_dir, 'a')
self.write_to_file(filename, doc, z)
z.close()
response = HttpResponse(z,content_type='application/zip')
response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=%s" % zip_dir
return response
```

And my template:

```
<a href="{% url '' %}"  class="btn btn-warning"> Download</a>
```

I am new to programming. So, I am still learning how to write urlpatterns.

Comment: show your urls please

Comment: url(r"^download_zip_file/$",SearchView.as_view(),name="lexisnexisearch.SearchView") .